# Find max entry for each hour rolling in Athena SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am working on a requirement where I have record for user's search history. I want to find out the latest record for a customer for each hour rolling. For example, the user can search at 10:10 and 11:00 hrs. Since these records happened in 1 hour time frame, I want the search which was made at 11:00 hrs.
Example input:

```
customerid, query_string, searchrequestat
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 06:38:51.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 06:50:51.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 07:30:51.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 07:52:00.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 08:12:00.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 09:50:56.000
2, qs2, 2023-05-25 06:23:06.000
2, qs2, 2023-05-25 05:33:46.000
```

Sample Output:

```
customerid, query_string, searchrequestat
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 06:50:51.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 08:12:00.000
1, qs1, 2023-05-25 09:50:56.000
2, qs2, 2023-05-25 06:23:06.000
```

Logic I want is:

```
Window 1 - 09:50 (1 hour from 09:50) - Max is 09:50
Window 2 - 08:12 - 07:52 - 07:30 (1 hour from 08:12) - Max is 08:12
Window 3 - 06:50 - 06:38 (1 hour from 06.50) - Max is 06:50
```

Basically I want to group together the records that are 1 hour apart (I want to use the max(searchrequestat) as base) and then pick the record with highest timestamp among them. I tried using the self join like below

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY searchrequestat DESC) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT le.*, ri.customerid AS right_customerid
    FROM your_table le
    JOIN your_table ri
    ON le.customerid = ri.customerid
    WHERE date_diff('hour', le.searchrequestat, ri.searchrequestat) <= 1
      AND le.searchrequestat <= ri.searchrequestat
  )
) AS subquery
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The problem with this SQL is it just returns 1 row per customerid.

Comment: Do you want to group rows that have a lesser than 1-hour gap, or you want groups whose overall duration does not exceed 1h? For example: if you had another row for customer `1` on `2023-05-25 07:50:00.000`, what would the result look like?

Comment: Updated the question with the above details!

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use a recursive query ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nfWClEFi)) if it works in AWS, and according to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html) it is available.